# Firebase Dart with Email and Password Authentication

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Dart Wrapper with email and password authentication and I get this error

> "Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase."

for both `createUser` and `authWithPassword`.  The email and password authentication provider is enabled in Firebase console and my ip address is whitelisted.

Any ideas as to how I would resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firebase Dart library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart) is built on top of Firebase SDK version 2.x.

If you created your Firebase project on the new Firebase Console, it will only work with the 3.x version of the JavaScript SDK. You'll need an updated version of the library, which doesn't seem to be available yet.

Alternatively, you can create a project on firebase.com and use the 2.x SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a small amount of interop code to make this work in dart.

```
 void login(String username, String password)
{
    var authRef = context['firebase'].callMethod("auth");
    var promisRef = authRef.callMethod('signInWithEmailAndPassword', [username, password]);
    //    JsObject promis2Ref = authRef.callMethod('signInWithEmailAndPassword');
    promisRef.callMethod("then", [onComplete, onLoginError]);
}

ZoneBinaryCallback onComplete(var user) {
    _logger.info("onComplete " + user['email']);
}

ZoneBinaryCallback onLoginError(var error) {
    _logger.info("onError" + error['code'] + " " + error['message']);

}
```